# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(\sin^2(x))}{x^2}\,dx$. My answer: $\pi\sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I think I have evaluated the following integral to be:

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(\sin^2(x))}{x^2}\,dx=\pi\sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}
$$
I want to know if my answer is correct and if not was my method wrong? Here is what I did.

I considered rewriting the integral over the whole real line as a sum of integrals that together span the real line. More specifically I did.

$$I= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(\sin^2(x))}{x^2}\,dx=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{(2n-1)\frac{\pi}{2}}^{(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\arctan(\sin^2(x))}{x^2}\,dx
$$
Then, considering we converge over this interval we make the substitution

$x\longrightarrow{x+n\pi}$

Which yields:

$$I=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arctan(\sin^2(x))\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(x+n\pi)^2}\,dx
$$
And since

$$\cot(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{x+n\pi}$$

It follows that

$$\csc^2(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(x+n\pi)^2}$$

So we finally get that

$$I=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\arctan(\sin^2(x))}{\sin^2(x)}\,dx=\pi\sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}
$$
Any thoughts?

Comment: Next time simply put dollar symbols around your mathematical expression for them to render correctly.

Comment: That is why you asked yesterday https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716356/evaluate-int-pi-2-pi-2-frac-arctan-sin2x-sin2xdx/4716861#4716861

Comment: This is the same author, who asked yesterday and want to solve the integral in this OP. @AnneBauval

Comment: @AnneBauval Look at the denominator. Sure, the solution to this requires the solution to the link, but that doesn't mean it is a duplicate.

Comment: To be clear, I’m not trying to duplicate a post, I merely want to see if my solution process especially the part with the series representation of the integral is correct or not from people more knowledgeable than me on the subject. I also posted this to see if anyone had any other methods of solving this integral as well.

Answer (score 2):

Noting that the integrand can be expressed as

$$
\qquad\qquad  I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan \left(\sin ^2(x)\right)}{x^2} d x= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan \left(\sin ^2 x\right)}{\sin ^2 x} \cdot\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 d x
$$
and satisfying

> $$ \qquad\qquad  \frac{\arctan \left(\sin ^2(x)\right)}{\sin^2x} = \frac{\arctan \left(\sin ^2(\pi+x)\right)}{\sin^2(\pi+x)} = \frac{\arctan \left(\sin ^2(\pi-x)\right)}{\sin^2(\pi-x)} ,  \frac{\arctan \left(\sin ^2(-x)\right)}{\sin^2 (-x)} =  \frac{\arctan \left(\sin ^2(x)\right)}{\sin^2x}   $$

Using [Lobachevsky_integral_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobachevsky_integral_formula), we have
$$I= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan \left(\sin ^2(x)\right)}{x^2} d x= \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\arctan \left(\sin ^2 x\right)}{\sin ^2 x}dx= \pi \sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}-1)} $$
where the last answer can be referred to the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4716594/732917).

Comment: Lai, what is the proof of Lobachevsky integral formula ? Could you write it or put a link containing the proof ?

Comment: You may read this article https://hal.science/hal-01539895v2/document. Wish it  helps.

Comment: Lai, it seems to be the same proof that the OP wrote in his question. Am I wrong?

Comment: OP’s solution is more detailed.  I am lazy and just use a famous trick.

Comment: Lai, I was speaking about the proof of Lobachevsky formula in that link you gave me, that proof seems to be the same one that the OP wrote in his question. Do you agree with me or am I wrong?

Comment: Lai, what does your picture profile represent? A visual proof of the equality $\,\cos36\unicode{176}=\frac12+\cos72\unicode{176}\,?$

Comment: @Angelo How exactly is Lai's answer the same as the OP's attempt?

Comment: @Accelerator, read the article https://hal.science/hal-01539895v2/document and then you will understand why.

Comment: @Angelo May you show me which part of the article makes you think the two answers are the same?

Comment: $Accelerator, Lai has applied the same method used in the article. Cannot you see it by yourself?